# What are some examples of space $l^2(N)$?

Tags: vector-spaces

I have a physics background and recently  came across the notion of $l^2(N)$ space defined as *the set of functions $f:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, such that the sum $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} |f(j)|^2$ is finite*. I want to know some examples of such spaces.

Comment: Not **a** set but **the** set.

Comment: This is more of an engineering example that arisis in estimation. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2486097/hilbert-space-valued-l2-random-variables  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2505202/what-is-the-space-of-random-variables-equipped-with-the-expectation-inner-produc

Comment: @MoisheKohan, thanks and corrected!

Comment: It is just one space. What do you mean by examples of such spaces?

Comment: Perhaps you want examples of elements inside of this space (not that the space is singular: there is only one such space). An example of an element is the function/sequence $f(n)=\frac{1}{n}$ if $n\neq 0$ and say $f(0)=0$ (it doesn’t really matter how you define the function at finitely many points), because as you hopefully know from single-variable calculus, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}<\infty$. An even more obvious example is the sequence $\delta_n:\Bbb{N}\to\Bbb{C}$ defined by $\delta_n(m)$ equal to $1$ if $n=m$ and $0$ else (often written as $e_n=(0,\dots, 1,0,\dots)$, in nth spot).

Comment: A very general context of use : the list of coefficients $(c_0, c_1, ...)$ of any Fourier series decomposition, considering [Parseval theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_theorem).