# How to define the covariance of an inner product space valued random variable in a basis invariant way?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, vector-spaces

Let $(V,g)$ be an $n$-dimensional vector space with the inner product $g.$ Let $X:\Omega\to (V, g)$ be a random variable taking values in that inner product space. I was wondering how to define the covariance of $X?$ I believe it has to be a linear endomorphisms of $V,$ and not a matrix (unless we choose a basis)

When $V=R^n, g$ the standard inner product on $R^n.$ There we define covariance as a matrix $C$ where $C(i,j)=cov(X_i,X_j), X=(X_1\dots X_n).$ I'm trying to generalize this to any $n$-dimensional vector space $V$ with an inner product $g$ as follows:

Let $B:=(e_1\dots e_n)$ be a $g$- orthonormal ordered basis for $V.$ Let $X_i:= g(X,e_i):\Omega \to R.$ So $X_i$'s are component of $X$ w.r.t. this orthonormal basis $B.$ Let $C_B$ be the $n$ by $n$ matrix defined by $C_B(i,j)=cov(X_i,X_j).$ Then we can attempt to define the covariance of $X$ as a linear map from $V$ to $V$ as follows:

Let $v=\sum_{i=1}^{n}v_ie_i, v':=(v_1\dots v_n)^{T}\in R^n$ is its coordinate (column) vector in the basis $B.$ Then $cov(X):V\to V$ is defined by what it does to the coordinate vector of $v:$

$cov(X)(v')=C_B v'.$

**Here are my questions:**

i) Is this a correct definition?

ii) How do I show that the definition **doesn't depend on the chosen basis $B?$**

iii) Can I **define the covariance where $V$ is just a vector space, not an inner product space?**

iv) Do you have **resources** for this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $V^*$ be the (continuous) dual space of $V$.  For $f \in V^*$, we write $f(X)$ for the real-valued random variable $f \circ X$.  Then you can define the covariance of $X$ as a quadratic form $q$ on $V^*$ via
$$q(f,g) = \operatorname{Cov}\left(f(X), g(X)\right).$$
You can easily check that $q$ is bilinear, symmetric, and positive semidefinite.

You can also define a covariance operator $A : V^* \to V$ as the unique linear operator satisfying $q(f,g) = g(Af)$.  When $V$ is a Hilbert space, you can identify $V^*$ with $V$ via the Riesz representation theorem, and then $A$ agrees with the usual definition of the covariance matrix.

These definitions can be found in *Gaussian Measures* by V. Bogachev (Definition 2.2.7).  Another reference is *Probability in Banach Spaces* by Ledoux and Talagrand.

This doesn't really make sense on a general vector space without additional structure.  In order to define the notion of a $V$-valued random variable in the first place, you at least need to equip $V$ with a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}$.  Normally this arises by having $V$ be a *topological* vector space and then letting $\mathcal{B}$ be the Borel $\sigma$-algebra.  Once $V$ has a topology then the above definitions make sense.   Of course, when $V$ is finite dimensional it only has one reasonable topology anyway, so requiring it to be a topological vector space is no restriction.

We have to use the dual space $V^*$ of *continuous* linear functionals, because for an *arbitrary* linear functional $f$ on $V$, there is no reason for $f(X)$ to be measurable and so it need not be a random variable.  (We could work instead with Borel linear functionals, but it turns out in many settings, e.g. Banach spaces, that every Borel linear functional is continuous anyway.)

Comment: Many thnaks for your answer, that I just accepted. I'll study the resources in detail and may come back with further questions just in case I have any. Thanks again, appreciate it!